# Сохранение свернутого меню при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста с такой проблемой. На странице есть левый сайдбар и кнопка, которая его сворачивает.

[меню в развернутом состоянии](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DldT5.png)

[меню в свернутом состоянии](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLph0.png)

Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу сайта сохранялось состояние сайдбара(свернутое или развернутое).

Код кнопки в котором расположена кнопка:

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
     <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button" title="Свернуть меню">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     </a>           
</nav>
```

При нажатии на кнопку, в тег `<body>` добавляется стиль `sidebar-mini`, если сайдбар раскрыт, при повторном нажатии, этот стиль убирается и сайдбар разворачивается.

Как мне привязаться к этой кнопке, каким-то событием, чтобы отлавливать состояние сайдбара и где, средствами php, хранить это состояние?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать session, cookie или localstorage. Просто добавьте boolean типа переменную, к примеру isOpen в одно из хранилищ на клиентской стороне. По клику же присваивайте ей isOpen = !isOpen, разумеется сохраняя в хранилище заново.

Comment: Спасибо, буду копать в эту сторону!